# Running multiple programs with one Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-leonardo, c#

Is it a problem to use multiple softwares to read the data that came from the same USB port simultaneously?

I have a board connected to a PC by USB, which is read by an application developed in C#. I display the data from the board in a table form.

Now I have to plot the data. The problem is that both the board and the software are deployed and can't be modified. So I have to create another program to do that, but the user should be able to run both softwares simultaneously.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are running Linux you can do this in a few lines of shell script; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361531/how-to-duplicate-dev-ttyusb0-stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not so much about Arduino, but about PC serial ports. There are programs/drivers out there that allow a user to "split" a serial port into two or more virtual serial ports, each of which can be opened by separate Windows applications, such as your C# programs.

Some of these programs or drivers are commercial and not free, and some are free.

https://www.fabulatech.com/serial-port-splitter-help/serial-port-splitting.html

http://www.eterlogic.com/help/vspe/UsageSplitPage.html

http://www.aggsoft.com/tcp-com/tcp-com-com-splitting.htm